# Unable to connect to MySQL Amazon RDS from Java app on Elastic Beanstalk, java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: java, mysql, driver, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I have a Java web application (REST API) that talks to a mysql database.

It works perfectly on my localhost, and on a standalone EC2 server running Tomcat and MySql, however when I deploy on [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) it cannot connect to [Amazon Relational Data Service](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/).

I get the following error message:

```
22:09:18,757 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:1831 - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:289)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
```

I'm running Mysql 5.5, and it is a Java 7 application.

To get the Java 7 WAR file to run I have a config file in `.ebextensions` as per:
http://qslack.com/2012/12/using-java-1-7-on-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

I have reviewed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.rds.html, and the only thing I haven't done is

> To connect to Tomcat RDS environments you must load the driver
>   explicitly using Class.forName() prior to the call to
>   DriverManager.getConnection() in the Java code.

as I'm using Spring (3.2.0) and Hibernate (4.1.9) to make the DB connection.  Having said that I did try to add this to one of my methods as a test but it didn't work.

I have connected successfully from the command line on the elastic beanstalk ec2 instance, and also from my personal computer, so it's not a permissions/access issue.

I have the mysql connector/j jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar) in my WebContent/WEB-INF/lib directory. I have also tried manually copying this jar file to `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` but this did not help.

It seems to be a problem that several people have come across but none of the proposed solutions seem to work. e.g:

https: //forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=413533
https: //forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=285923&tstart=0#285923

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that Elastic Beanstalk was adding quotes around the JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING environment variable that I was passing in.

The issue and solution is described in this thread:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115043

(Adding the following to my .ebextensions config fixed the issue):

```
commands: 
     patch_tomcat:
         command: sed -i.bak s#\"/usr/sbin/tomcat7\"#\"/usr/sbin/tomcat7-elasticbeanstalk\"#g /etc/init.d/tomcat7
```